# Servlet not found 404 error

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am trying to call a `servlet` from my html form. My `web.xml` file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>apphome</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <display-name>ControllerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.main.servlets.Controller</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My `servlet` is located under `src/com/main/servlets/Controller`
My form action is `"ControllerServlet"`
I don't have any annotations in my Controller class.

When I submit the form, I get a **404**. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What URI are you hitting?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/apphome/ControllerServlet

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/apphome/Controller ...

Comment: You've put `/Controller` as your url pattern..., so why hit `/ControllerServlet`?

Comment: post the code for the servlet impl, without it it's difficult to tell you what are you missing.

Answer (score 3):

The servlet is mapped to the url pattern `/Controller`. The unique URL to reach this servlet is thus `http://localhost:8080/apphome/Controller`.

Comment: So my form action should be "/Controller"?

Comment: `/Controller` is an absolute path. As a relative path, from `home.html`, for instance, it should be just `Controller` (without the slash).

Comment: Ok, when I submit my form, I get directed to:  http://localhost:8080/apphome/Controller (Now I get a 500 error ClassNotFoundException on the Controller class

Comment: Your form action should use a correct relative path, or an absolute path with the context path prepended (`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Controller`), or an absolute path using the JSTL (`<c:url value='/Controller' />`). the last one being my preferred solution, by far.

Comment: Regarding the error 500, that's another problem, indicating that a class is missing. You probably forgot to add a library to WEB-INF/lib. The name of the missing class should tell you which one(s).

Answer (score 0):

use this:

http://localhost:8080/apphome/servlet/Controller

this extra servlet here before the Controller specifies the servlet container
you need to put this up!